# How to get an actual direction like east - west in unity?

Tags: google-maps, unity-game-engine, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

I am using google API to show a map in unity and also generate object on map's location from player position. Now I want to know actual direction. It means identify direction (east-west) from google maps or google API.

> I made a code but it doesn't give me actual direction.

```
 var v = transform.forward;
 v.y = 0;
 v.Normalize();

 if (Vector3.Angle(v, Vector3.forward) <= 45.0) {
     Debug.Log("North");
 }
 else if (Vector3.Angle(v, Vector3.right) <= 45.0) {
     Debug.Log("East");
 }
 else if (Vector3.Angle(v, Vector3.back) <= 45.0) {
     Debug.Log("South");
 }
 else {
     Debug.Log("West");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

using `Vector3.forward`

> Shorthand for writing `new Vector3(0, 0, 1)`.

returns you the forward Z axis direction of Unity itself. This depends entirely on the orientation of your device when you started Unity/your app and has nothing to do with real world coordinates.

---

You are probably rather looking for [`Compass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass.html) which returns the actual orientation of your phone e.g. using [`magneticHeading`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass-magneticHeading.html)

> The heading in degrees relative to the **magnetic** North Pole.
>
> The value in this property is always measured relative to the top of
>   the screen in its current orientation. The heading of magnetic north
>   is not exactly the same as true geographical north - to get the exact
>   heading, use the [`trueHeading`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass-trueHeading.html) property.
>
> ```c#
> public class Example : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     void Update()
>     {
>         // Orient an object to point to magnetic north.
>         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -Input.compass.magneticHeading, 0);
>     }
> }
> ```

or using the [`trueHeading`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass-trueHeading.html)

> The heading in degrees relative to the **geographic** North Pole.
>
> The value in this property is always measured relative to the top of
>   the screen in its current orientation. Note, that if you want this
>   property to contain a valid value, you must also enable location
>   updates by calling `Input.location.Start()`.
>
> ```c#
> using UnityEngine;
>
> public class Example : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     void Start()
>     {
>         Input.location.Start();
>     }
>
>     void Update()
>     {
>         // Orient an object to point northward.
>         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -Input.compass.trueHeading, 0);
>     }
> }
> ```

---

So for your use case you would simply use e.g.

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public enum Heading
{
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West
}

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Debug")]
    [SerializeField] [Range(0f, 360f)] private float northHeading;

    [Header("OutputValues")]
    [SerializeField] private float myHeading;
    [SerializeField] private float dif;
    [SerializeField] private Heading heading;

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        // only use the Y component of the objects orientation
        // always returns a value between 0 and 360
        myHeading = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        // also this is always a value between 0 and 360
        northHeading = Input.compass.magneticHeading;

        dif = myHeading - northHeading;
        // wrap the value so it is always between 0 and 360
        if (dif < 0) dif += 360f;

        if (dif > 45 && dif <= 135)
        {
            heading = Heading.East;
        }
        else if (dif > 135 && dif <= 225)
        {
            heading = Heading.South;
        }
        else if (dif > 225 && dif <= 315)
        {
            heading = Heading.West;
        }
        else
        {
            heading = Heading.North;
        }
    }

    // Only for debug and demo
    // draw a pointer towards north
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        var northDirection = (Quaternion.Euler(0, northHeading, 0) * Vector3.forward).normalized;

        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + northDirection);

        var objectDirection = (Quaternion.Euler(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0) * Vector3.forward).normalized;
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + objectDirection);
    }
}
```

---

In the little demo you can see the blue pointer for the object's forward direction and the red vector for the north direction. You can see how the `Heading` enum value changes according to the objects orientation.

*Since I did it on a PC I had to manually "adjust" a north direction, later you will get this from your phone.*

[image]